# I just started to learn java. I am trying to make a program that takes in decimal. But it gives me error when i enter a decimal

Tags: input, double

package com.Pramesh;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrameshShrestha {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your first number");
    double num1 = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter your second number");
    double num2 = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("The total is:  " + (num1 + num2));

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To input a double number, for example 2.5 you need to write on the console `2,5`

Comment: Actually, it worked. But why is that?

Comment: to be honest idk why, in some countries life France the normal way to write decimal is with ","